# How to define implicit class for Traversable with CanBuildFrom?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm trying to add some methods to `Traversable` trait by pimping via `implicit class`.

But I'm kind of lost with `CanBuildFrom` trait. Consider the following:

```
implicit class TraversableExt[+A, +Repr <: Traversable[A]](traversable: Repr) {
  def debug[That](name: String)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, That]): That =
    traversable.map{ a => println(name + ": " + a); a }(bf)
}
```

This fails with error:

> Error:(21, 59) type mismatch;
>     found   : scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,A,That]
>     required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Traversable[A],A,That]
>         traversable.map{ a => println(name + ": " + a); a }(bf)
>                                                             ^

I'm guessing that since `Repr` in `CanBuildFrom[-Repr, -Elem, +To]` is contravariant and thus my `Repr` which is upper-bound by `Traversable[A]` may not work.

But overall, I'm pretty lost. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `TraversableLike` and higher kinded types to make the type inferencer happy and make it work with `CanBuildFrom`:

```
implicit class TraversableExt[A, C[X] <: TraversableLike[X, C[X]]](traversable: C[A]) {
  def debug[That](name: String)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[C[A], A, That]): That =
    traversable.map{ a => println(name + ": " + a); a }(bf)
}
```

The compiler is now able to correctly infer the type of your collection `C[A]` instead of generically look for a `CanBuildFrom[Traversable[A],...]`

As a rule of thumb, when you want to return the same collection class as the one passed in, you have to use the `*Like` classes